# Seeding data in a Mongo db within a linked Docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, sails.js, fig

I'm using [`fig`](http://www.fig.sh) to deploy my `Node.js` app.

`fig.yml`

```
web:
  build: .
  command: node app.js
  links:
   - db
  ports:
   - "1337:1337"

db:
  image: dockerfile/mongodb
```

Running `fig run db env` gives me the following environment vars:

```
DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.29:27017
DB_PORT_27017_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.29:27017
DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.29
DB_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT=27017
DB_PORT_27017_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_PORT_28017_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.29:28017
DB_PORT_28017_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.29
DB_PORT_28017_TCP_PORT=28017
DB_PORT_28017_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_NAME=/pos_db_run_3/db
```

My app's `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
# Pull base image.
FROM dockerfile/nodejs

# install mongo client
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y dnsutils
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-shell

# copy the source files into the image
COPY . /data/myapp

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data/myapp

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Create default database and user
RUN mongo $DB_PORT < seed-mongo

RUN node/seed.js

EXPOSE 1337

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

However the build is failing at `RUN mongo $DB_PORT < seed-mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
2014-11-20T20:47:59.193+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-20T20:47:59.195+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
Service 'web' failed to build: The command [/bin/sh -c mongo $DB_PORT < seed-mongo] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

According to the [fig docs](http://www.fig.sh/yml.html#links) I'd be better off referring to the database simply as `db` so I tried

```
RUN mongo db < seed-mongo
```

But this gave me

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: db
2014-11-20T21:08:11.154+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-20T21:08:11.156+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

So I injected a `RUN host db` in there just to see if `db` really is a host name.  And no, despite the docs above it's not.

```
Step 10 : RUN host db
 ---> Running in 73b4dc787c79
Host db not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Service 'web' failed to build: The command [/bin/sh -c host db] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So I'm stumped.

How am I supposed to talk to the `mongo` instance running in my linked `Docker` container?

Comment: afaik, something like `$DB_PORT` is not supported in docker file. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5584, except for WORKDIR https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2637

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the official mongo image? https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: Thanks Adrian I thought I was using the official images - my bad.  I've fixed that but it's still no closer to working for me. I'm clearly missing some logical step wrt seeding the db. Alternatively if I could find the default username for the mongo install then I could just use those values in my app and not need to seed the db with specific user / password for use by the app.

Comment: I think the biggest problem here (and why you can't find much Googling) is that you're trying to seed a database in a Dockerfile. This makes the Dockerfile unportable. You should really avoid that approach and instead have it do it with a start-up wrapper script (ran with either entrypoint or cmd). That script should check if the seeding is necessary, and seed only if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was a combination of insights from above, but mainly I stopped trying to seed a specific database and db user in the build phase and instead use `--host db_1` with no username or password. If I really need that functionality later I'll work it out.

I could then build the project and connect it to `mongo` in the other image.

In my `config/connections.js` I included:

```
development: {
  adapter  : 'sails-mongo',
  host     :  'db_1',
  port     :  27017,
  user     :  '',
  password :  '',
  database :  process.env.DB_NAME
},
```

and I changed the `CMD` to be `"node data/seeds.js && node app"`

Answer (score 3):

Your mongo container has ip address $DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR
So try with `mongo --host $DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR < seed-mongo`
You can't use it in a RUN statement I think, because the environment variables are not available at build-time. You could try using it in a CMD I guess.

Comment: My understanding is that anything in the CMD is run each time the image is run, which is not what I want. I just want to seed a database and user, and then push some seed data into that database as a separate step. But only on build. Not each time the container launches. I'd have thought this would be a very common use-case but days of searching has yielded nothing useful.

Comment: What about the ONBUILD instruction?

Answer (score 0):

You never exposed your Mongo port.

```
web:
  build: .
  command: node app.js
  links:
   - db
  ports:
   - "1337:1337"

db:
  image: dockerfile/mongodb
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Should not matter in this instance. The host does not need its port allocated for building another image.

Comment: the standard `mongo` image exposes that port anyway